# XSLT: Combine nodes based on given list

Tags: xml, xslt

Any idea how to achieve the desidered output with XSLT?

Source XML:

```
<results>
   <pageFunctionResult>
      <id>46555</id>
      <name>URC 90 S</name>
      <quantity>5+</quantity>
   </pageFunctionResult>
   <pageFunctionResult>
      <id>46556</id>
      <name>URC 90 M</name>
      <quantity>5+</quantity>
   </pageFunctionResult>
   <pageFunctionResult>
      <id>46557</id>
      <name>URC 90 L</name>
      <quantity>10+</quantity>
   </pageFunctionResult>
   <pageFunctionResult>
      <id>96555</id>
      <name>NICE</name>
      <quantity>5+</quantity>
   </pageFunctionResult>
   <pageFunctionResult>
      <id>26555</id>
      <name>NEW L</name>
      <quantity>5+</quantity>
   </pageFunctionResult>
   <pageFunctionResult>
      <id>26552</id>
      <name>NEW XXL</name>
      <quantity>5+</quantity>
   </pageFunctionResult>
</results>
```

I need somehow combine these elements based which are in the given list (it can be `xsl:variable`), for example:
`"URC 90", "NEW"`.

Let me show you an example output how it should look:

```
<results>
   <pageFunctionResult>
      <name>URC 90</name>
      <variantname>URC 90 S</variantname>
      <id>46555</id>
      <quantity>5+</quantity>
      <variant id="1">
         <id>46556</id>
         <name>URC 90 M</name>
         <quantity>5+</quantity>
      </variant>
      <variant id="2">
         <id>46557</id>
         <name>URC 90 L</name>
         <quantity>10+</quantity>
      </variant>
   </pageFunctionResult>
   <pageFunctionResult>
      <id>96555</id>
      <name>NICE</name>
      <quantity>5+</quantity>
   </pageFunctionResult>
   <pageFunctionResult>
      <name>NEW</name>
      <variantname>NEW L</variantname>
      <id>46555</id>
      <quantity>5+</quantity>
      <variant id="1">
         <id>26552</id>
         <name>NEW XXL</name>
         <quantity>5+</quantity>
      </variant>
   </pageFunctionResult>   
</results>
```

In the source XML we have item which is not in the given list: `NICE`. These nodes should be copied as it is (no need to modify).

What do you think guys, it is possible to achieve this output if we know part of the `<name>` element?

Comment: Do you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Yes, XSLT version doesn't matter. I use SAXON processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 sample which achieves the grouping as you want it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf">

    <xsl:param name="values" select="'NEW', 'URC 90'"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:match" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:param name="values" as="xs:string*"/>
        <xsl:sequence
            select="if ($values[matches($input, concat('^', .))])
                    then $values[matches($input, concat('^', .))]
                    else $input"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="results">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="pageFunctionResult" group-by="mf:match(name, $values)">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="name ne current-grouping-key()">
                            <xsl:copy>
                                <name>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                                </name>
                                <variantname>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                                </variantname>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="id, quantity"/>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() except ."/>
                            </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pageFunctionResult">
        <variant id="{position()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </variant>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh3R/1.

Comment: This is superbbb! There's one question left: can we add  ```<position>MAINPRODUCT</position>``` after pageFunctionResult (but not under variant)? I want to mark root elements.

Comment: I think you have added one approach to add that `position` element, instead of the `for-each select="current-group()"` you have used you could also the use push style processing with `apply-templates select="current-group()"`, in that case with a separate `mode`, as done in http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh3R/5.

Comment: Martin, what can be the problem if the regex fails for products with bracket in their name? Example: URC 90 (26)

Comment: @Adrian, in the regular expression language `()` are used to define groups of characters so to use them literally you need to escape them as `\(\)`. See http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_escape-for-regex.html for a function that does that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I am trying to implement in this way: http://xsltransform.net/ncntCS6 ...so far without success.

Comment: Consider to ask a new question for that problem, to use that function from functx you simply need to include it and then do e.g. ` <xsl:param name="values-unescaped" select="'Sniper 50 Red (26)'"/><xsl:param name="values" select="for $value in $values-unescaped return functx:escape-for-regex($value)"/>` I think but the rest of the grouping key comparison then becomes difficult. Ask a new question with the details, then I am sure you get help.

Comment: I am reviewing this old question, this XSLT works well, but now I have elements with similar names:  <xsl:param name="values" select="'NEW', 'NEW 27.5'"/>,  they are two different items: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWV8/2 or this example where Spider 90 and Spider 90 27.5 are two different items, but the XSLT combines as if they were the same: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nqn5Ya.

Comment: @Adrian, I think it is better asking a new question where you explain how you want to decide which of the search terms you want to select to group items, obviously the current algorithm is only looking for a partial match as that was part of the original requirement where you wanted to group items with e.g. `URC 90 S` and `URC 90 M` if the shared the beginning `URC 90`. If you now have more than one value partially matching an item we need to know which match comes first to identify a group.

Comment: See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nqn5Ya/1 which tries to sort the match strings by descending length first and that way only groups items if they share the longest possible match.

Comment: Tested this today, works perfectly. Unbelievable what you can do with XSLT.